# How do I navigate to a URL based on the user's selection from an option menu, in a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a feature and can't seem to find the right solution.

In a bootstrap modal, I have a drop down menu like so:

```
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form onsubmit='makePath(this);'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1">Select an item to add</label>
        <select id="select" class="form-control" id="createNewSelect">
          <option value="lease">Lease</option>
          <option value="sale">Sale</option>
          <option value="location">Location</option>

        </select>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Create</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Goal:

1. User launches the create modal
2. User selects item from dropdown
3. User navigates to the URL of the selected item when they click the create button.

I appreciate any help.

TK

Comment: For starters, for the onsubmit attribute to work the way you've outlined, the submit button needs to be a child of the form tag. Currently it is outside of it in the modal-footer

Comment: In addition to that, I believe you're looking to pass through the selected option. That's not the same as `this` in `makePath(this)`. You're looking for something like `document.getElementById('select')[document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex].value()`

Answer (score 0):

Well There are many ways to achieve that. Because bootstrap using jQuery...

```
$(function() {
   $('button[data-dismiss]').click(function()
   {
       window.location.href = $('#select').val()
   });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```
(function() {
  var dialog = $('#your-dialog-selector'), // Your dialog
      select = $('#createNewSelect'); // The select box (get rid of the second id attribute [id="select"]!)

  // Listen for the form's submit event
  select.closest('form').on('submit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // Don't actually submit

     window.location = "/" + select.val(); // Navigate
  });

  // To open the dialog.. put it wherever
  dialog.modal('show');
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the create button to get the vbalue of the select list - also not e that in your example - you have two id's for that select - each element can only have one id. Then you can build the link and use window.location to navigate to it. Note I just ised a google query to as the link - you will need to amend as needded.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('#createLink').click(function(){
    var sel = $('#createNewSelect').val();
    var link = "http:www.google.com/?q=" + sel;
    console.log(link);
    // use window.location = link; to allow navigation to the link location
    })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form onsubmit='makePath(this);'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1">Select an item to add</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="createNewSelect">
          <option value="lease">Lease</option>
          <option value="sale">Sale</option>
          <option value="location">Location</option>

        </select>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="createLink">Create</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write your URL targets in the option values.

```js
$("#create_btn").click(function() {
  var url = $('#select').val();
  // alert(url);
  window.location = url;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">

      <label for="exampleSelect1">Select an item to add</label>

      <select id="select" class="form-control" id="createNewSelect">
        <option value="http://google.com">Lease</option>
        <option value="http://amazon.com">Sale</option>
        <option value="http://test.com">Location</option>

      </select>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button id="create_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Create</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.  This solution does not appear to be passing the selected item back to the browser...

Comment: I just checked. Works like a charm for me. Have you tried in a real file? The new page is not shown inside the code playground.